# why does it seem to be good practice to set partition limits to whole MB values?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

recently I moved to a new hardware with all the joys and chores of learning how things changed and do work now.

when I came across the **re/partitioning task using gparted** it **automatically chose to set the partition limits to whole MB values**, thus leaving small gaps between the partitions occasionally.

now I wonder:

since it is only just an arbitrary number (especially when considering SSDs with their low-level storage controllers inside) where my partition starts or ends,

*why does it seem to be a good choice to leave those gaps on the drive*?

cheers

Comment: It's an interesting question, but even if your SSD is a smallish 128GB, you're talking about wasting less than 1/128,000th of your space.

Comment: As you said: its about the *why*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to do with partition alignment. Essentially, under the hood, your hard drive is divided into sectors. Whenever the hard drive performs an operation, it acts on the entire sector at once; that is to say, when it reads any data that is stored within a sector, it must read the entire sector. If data is split over multiple sectors, it must read the entirety of each of those sectors. The filesystem that goes on a partition also allocates the available space into blocks (the size of which is usually a tunable parameter at filesystem creation; for an FS which will consist primarly of small files you'd use a small block size, for something primarily large you'd use a large block size, the objective being to minimise wasted space - if a file is smaller than the block size, the rest of the block is wasted, but the smaller your block size, the larger the tables addressing all the blocks must be).

Now essentially you need your filesystem blocks and your disk sectors to be in alignment - one should fit in the other with no remainder, and crucially they should start at the same place, so there is no fractional overlap. Say you have a disk which has a 4kb sector size, and your filesystem is in 1kb blocks. If your partition starts at a small offset from the start of a sector - even if it's only a few bytes - every fourth block in your filesystem will actually be split over two sectors, so you must read/write both sectors on the disk whenever interacting with that block. That's a 25% overhead, which can quickly add up to a considerable reduction in performance. If your FS allocation block size is the same as your HD sector size (4k would not be unreasonable for both) and you have this offset, every single read/write would have this issue, which would be a massive performance impact.

In order to avoid this, we conservatively align the start of partitions with megabyte boundaries (as a megabyte should still be a nice multiple of the block/sector size even several years down the road with whatever massive drives we have then). This can result in tiny "gaps" on the disk if the partition sizes don't also neatly match up and end exactly on a megabyte boundary. There is always a gap left at the start of the disk because the first several sectors on the disk are reserved for other purposes.

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Partition_Alignment describes the issue in more specific detail. However, as pointed out, the space lost compared to the size of a modern disk is pretty trivial.

Comment: Note that some types of RAID require alignment on power-of-2 number of sectors, which typically works out to 64KiB to 256KiB, but sometimes more than that. SSDs have their own needs, which *usually* work well with 1MiB alignment. The Advanced Format need for 4KiB alignment, and typical RAID requirements, are evenly divisible into 1MiB. Thus, 1MiB is a useful default for most modern disk technologies. At worst, you lose something under 1MiB of disk space as the cost of ensuring good disk performance.

Answer (score 1):

> why does it seem to be a good choice to leave those gaps on the drive?

That seems to be a use of "guard bands".
Sometimes I'd see the (intentional?) non-allocation of the last track or two at the end of a partition.
In theory they should not be necessary.

For a hard disk drive, partitions used to be allocated to start on a cylinder boundary.  Such an allocation would minimize the number of seeks within the partition, and thus improve overall access times.
But nowadays with HDDs using zone bit recording, the partitioning program really doesn't know the actual drive geometry and where the physical cylinders are, so any "cylinder alignment" is essentially meaningless.

For a solid state drive, partitions need to be allocated to occupy an integral number of erase blocks.  Since NAND flash chips size their R/W sectors and pages and erase blocks in powers of 2, sizing and aligning SSD partition in units of a large power of 2 such as 1 Megabyte is presumed to encompass an integral number of such pages/blocks.

Comment: +1 about aligning flash erase blocks. I've read that mis-aligned partitions could try to erase 512 bytes, but actually end up erasing & re-writing 1 or 2 megs (or more?). Even that may not sound like much, but if your FS updates every file's access time for every read, it can add up